# Android ListView center selection

Tags: java, android

I have a ListView that shows the closest word matches to a search.

For example if I search "hi" I get the following results in the ListView

...
**hi**
hi five
hi-five
high
highlight
....

I am using

```
ListView.setSelection(wordList.indexOf(searchWord));
ListView.setSelected(true);
```

The above code puts the selected word "hi" at the top and doesnt highlight the selection.

I want the "hi" to be centrally positioned , selected and highlighted automatically.
See below

...
hello
hello there
**hi**
hi-five
hi five
...

What code can I use to achieve the above?

Many thanks.

Comment: I'm also looking for a way to center a ListView...

Comment: did U did it?can u post the code

Answer (score 2):

```
ListView view = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.YourListView);

int height = view.getHeight();
int itemHeight = view.getChildAt(0).getHeight();
view.setSelectionFromTop(position, height/2 - itemHeight/2);
```

---

The position (int) is the listitem you want to center in the listview!!

Comment: view.getHeight() can return 0

Answer (score 0):

try `setSelectionFromTop()` you'll have to do the math yourself. setSelection() bring the selected item to the top of the view, which is what you are seeing.

Answer (score 0):

try this.
first, get visible item count of listview

```
int count=0;
for (int i = 0; i  <= listview.getLastVisiblePosition(); i++)
{
    if (listview.getChildAt(i)!= null)
    {
        count++; 
    }
}
```

second, scroll the item to the center of listview.

```
int target = position-count/2;
if (target<0) target = 0;
listview.setSelection(target);
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
ListView lv = getListView();
  lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
   lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
        int position, long id) {
      // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ((TextView) view).getText(),
          Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
  });
```

for more information :
http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html