# Center align selected item in new master detail activity

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-activity

In my application, i am launching a new activity on a button click. User will enter a student ID and press the button. On button click, a new activity will be launched with master detail view. In left side master view, all the students are displayed in a list view. Each list view item shown which will have a image and the student id below the image. Whatever student id user has entered in previous screen will get selected in listview and on right hand side thats students detailed information is stored.

I want to align the selected student at the center of screen in the new activity so that user can have a better view and he can easily scroll to previous or next students. How i can center align the selected listview item in the new activity automatically when its launched?

Thanks in advance,

IamHuM

Comment: refer to [chris](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5540223/center-a-listview-on-its-current-selection) answer.

Answer (score 0):

try this snippet,

```
 int height = listview.getHeight();
int itemHeight = listview.getChildAt(0).getHeight();
listview.setSelectionFromTop(centeredItemPosition, height/2 - itemHeight/2);
```